# Positioning multiple dialog boxes using jQuery UI

Tags: html, jquery-ui

How can I position Dialog Boxes side-by-side in relation to their containing div, rather than in the whole window?

I am using jQuery UI: : http://carvalhar.com/componente/jQueryDialogr/index.html#

Comment: well you will have to modify the plug in o dont think they might have given any functionality to do so

Answer (score 0):

You can change the position property for the jQuery UI Dialog. Dialogr inherits all the properties of the normal UI Dialog. You can have a look about positioning it at this link

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

You can change the position co-ordinates for the two dialogs to stack them together.